# Pop-ups don't appear on Android in Unity, how can I fix it?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I tried to ask user for permission for read memory on Android device but nothing works. Then I tried to check internal code of Unity (Permission struct in UnityEngine.Android), and there was empty function. The version of my unity 2020.3.15f2. Then I tried to use earlier version of Unity but there the Permission struct was different. It's my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;

public class Perm : MonoBehaviour
{
    readonly string[] _permissions = {Permission.ExternalStorageRead, Permission.ExternalStorageWrite};

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead);
#endif
        RequestPermission();
        StartCoroutine(FckIt());
    }

    public void RequestPermission()
    {
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead))
            Permission.RequestUserPermissions(_permissions);
    }

    IEnumerator FckIt()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
        RequestPermission();
    }
}
```

There are a lot of repetitions here - I tried to fix the error myself but it didn't work out.